Clarke regularity of piecewise linear functions
Let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, be a Lipschtiz continuous piecewise linear function.

Is this sufficient to guarantee that $f$ is Clarke-regular (Definition 2.3.4 in [1])?

If the answer is in the positive, does the result extend to piecewise $C^\infty$ functions?


In either case, I would appreciate a sketch of a proof, or a counterexample.
[1] FH Clarke, Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis
Thanks!

What is the definition of Clarke-regular? I do not own the book.

@SeverinSchraven It asks if the (one sided) generalised directional derivative is the same as the (one sided) directional derivative.

@copper.hat Thanks. Nice counterexample :)

Let $f(x) = -|x|$, then $f'(0;1) = -1$, but $f^\circ(0;1) = 1$. Hence the answer is negative.
Note that $f^\circ(x,;h) = \limsup_{ y \to x, t \downarrow 0} {f(y+th)-f(y) \over h}$, this is from Section 2.1 of Clarke's book.

Thanks for the answer. Admittedly, I did not expect such benign functions to fail the Clarke regularity condition. This was a potential approach to answer this other question (inapplicable given the counterexample). Any answer to the latter are very welcome too!
